# % after end="" in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple string reversal program in python3, but when the program outputs the result, it outputs a % immediately after. ex: hello becomes olleh%.

My code:

```
def reverseString(userString):
    stringLength = len(userString) - 1
    while stringLength >= 0:
        print(userString[stringLength], end="", flush=True)
        stringLength = stringLength - 1

reverseString(input("Enter a string: "))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `%` your shell prompt or anything like that?

Comment: When I run your code, I see no % sign.  Is it possible it's some sort of system prompt that you're returning to after the program runs?

Comment: just this code shall do ? raw_input('enter a string: ')[::-1]

Answer (score -1):

```
def reverseString(userString):
    return print('{}'.format(userString[::-1]))

reverseString(input("Enter a string: "))
```

this will be a lot simpler and faster

Answer (score -1):

the pythonic way is to less iterate - use a more descriptive way to write your code.
I know tis looks a bit awkward in the beginning but you'll get used to it

```
def reverseString(userString):
    return (userString[::-1])
```

about the `%` sign - it's probably what your python repl shows at the end.
you can probably ignore it...